# parsing robots.txt file using c++

Tags: c++, regex, boost, robots.txt

is there is any library to parse `robots.txt`, and if it does not exist, how can i write it in c++ with boost regex?

Comment: Need more details:  What is the format and layout of robots.txt?  Are you questioning how to write using regular expressions or how to read?

Comment: "Robots.txt" is the exclusion mechanism for web crawlers. See e.g. http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html . It's a trivial format.

Comment: Not sure why people are voting to close this as not being a real question.  Maybe it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751387/what-is-wrong-with-this-boost-c-regex-code , though.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) in the Boost Regex library.  If you edit your question to give a better idea of what exactly you are looking for in your robots.txt file, someone can help you with the Regex syntax.

For example, if you are trying to find the names of all User-agents in the file, you could use an expression like this.

```
boost::regex expression("^User-agent:\s*(.*)");
```